# How to count each char from varchar field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need to get character and character count. The character with the highest character count will be reported first. How to count each char from varchar field?

```
CREATE TABLE name(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    value TEXT
);
INSERT INTO name (value) VALUES ('abcd');
INSERT INTO name (value) VALUES ('abcd efg');
INSERT INTO name (value) VALUES ('m');
```

My ouput expected

```
a 2
b 2
c 2
d 2
e 1
f 1
g 1
m 1
```

I wrote a query which got only single letter

```
SELECT 
 sum( 
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(value)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( value, 'a', '') ) 
        ) / LENGTH('a')        
    )) AS a    
FROM name
```

Comment: Considering tagging with [only] **one** database implementation.

Comment: Can there be same character multiple times in a field ? eg: `aaabcdef` ?

Comment: yes, same characters in multiple times also there

Comment: @Maws then the count is based on the number of rows the character is in ? or the total number of occurrences of the character ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Are you sure the OP is using MySQL?

Comment: @Laurenz Maybe keep your answer until we know the database for sure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will change it to generic SQL tag. as OP has not clarified yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of all characters using `string_to_array()` and unnest, and then group that result:

```
select t.c, count(*)
from name, unnest(string_to_array(value,null)) as t(c)
where t.c <> ' '
group by t.c
order by count(*) desc
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/JXYR32728

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a calendar table approach here:

```
SELECT
    t1.letter,
    COUNT(t2.name) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT 'a' AS letter UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 'z'
) t1
LEFT JOIN names t2
    ON t2.name LIKE '%' || t1.letter || '%'
GROUP BY
    t1.letter
ORDER BY
    t1.letter;
```

### Demo

Note that this reports all letters in the alphabet, even if they have a zero count.  If you only want to see positive counts, then add the following to the end of the query:

```
HAVING COUNT(t2.name) > 0
```

Comment: @Maws first of all, Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: postgressql, version 10

Comment: @Maws I edited my answer for Postgres, q.v. the demo.

Comment: SELECT     t1.letter,     COUNT(t2.name) AS cnt FROM (SELECT 'a' 
AS letter UNION ALL     SELECT 'b' UNION ALL     SELECT 'c' ) t1 
LEFT JOIN names t2     ##ERROR: relation "names" does not exist
ON t2.name LIKE '%' || t1.letter || '%' GROUP BY     t1.letter ORDER BY     t1.letter;

Comment: I didn't use the exact same table names as you.  Check the demo please.

Comment: @Tim can you tell which table name you have used. sorry not an expert in mysql,

Comment: I got output in (mysql) https://rextester.com/XZPFF69021, but throwing error in postgressql

Comment: My demo above in DBFiddle is working _completely_ correctly.  Your code has a problem, not my answer.